# $A\cap B = A\cap C$ and $A\cup B = A\cup C$. Show $B=C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I couldn't gather an idea on how prove that. I tried to form union of $B$ on both sides of equation one just to try if it takes me anywhere:

$$B \cup (A\cap B) = B \cup(A\cap C)$$
$$(B\cup A) \cap (B\cup B) = (B\cup A) \cap (B\cup C) $$

but it didn't. any ideas?

Comment: consider any $x$ with $x \in B$ but $x \not \in C$

Comment: There already are several questions on this site about this exact question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522720/is-my-proof-for-a-cap-b-a-cap-c-longleftrightarrow-b-c-correct
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783226/use-direct-proof-to-prove-if-a-cap-b-a-cap-c-and-a-cup-b-a-cup-c-t
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951669/let-a-b-and-c-be-sets-if-a-cup-b-a-cup-c-and-a-cap-b
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958465/verifying-my-proof-of-b-c
(And maybe you can find more.)

Comment: I found the above links either [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24A%5Ccap%20B%20%3D%20A%5Ccap%20C%24%2C%20%24A%5Ccup%20B%20%3D%20A%5Ccup%20C%24%2C%20%24B%3DC%24&p=1) or [via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22A\cap+B+=+A\cap+C%22%22A\cup+B+=+A\cup+C%22+%22B=C$%22+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

$B = B \cap (B \cup A) = B \cap (C \cup A) = (B \cap C) \cup (B \cap A) = (C \cap B) \cup (C \cap A) = C \cap (B \cup A) = C \cap (C \cup A) = C$

Comment: can you please explain what you did?

Comment: +1, brilliant! (For OP, the answer uses the fact that intersection and union distribute over each other.)

Comment: @MohitSaxena I used basic set identity principles: Absorption ($A\cap (A\cup B) = A$), Distribution ($A\cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$), and Commutation ($A \cap B = B \cap A$).

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Grazie! The power of algebra!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Suppose $B\neq C$

$\implies \exists x\in B : \; x\notin C$

$$\implies x\in A\cup B$$
$$\implies x\in  A\cup C$$

$$\implies x\in A$$

$$\implies x\in A\cap B$$

$$\implies x\in A\cap C$$

$$\implies x\in C$$

Contradiction, so...

Answer (score 0):

We have $(i) \ A\cap B=A\cap C$ and $(ii) \ A\cup B=A\cup C$. Suppose that $b\in B$ but $b\notin C$. Then, if $b\in A$, we have a contradiction on $(i)$. If $b\notin A$, we got a contradiction on $(ii)$. We have the same for any $c\in C$ such that $c\notin B$. So, $B=C$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the symmetric difference $A \Delta B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ it follows that:

$$A \Delta B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \cup C) \setminus (A \cap C) = A \Delta C$$

Then, using the associativity of $\Delta$ and the facts that $A \Delta \emptyset = A$ and $A \Delta A = \emptyset$:

$$B = \emptyset \Delta B = (A \Delta A) \Delta B = A \Delta (A \Delta B) = A \Delta (A \Delta C) = (A \Delta A) \Delta C = \emptyset \Delta C = C$$