# Set theory: Prove if $A \cup B = A \cap B$ then $A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> The question provides an answer, saying:
>
> 1. $A \subset A \cup B$, then, $A \cap B \subset B$, then $A \subset B$
> 2. $B \subset A \cup B$, then, $A \cap B \subset A$, then $B \subset A$
>
> (1) and (2) $\Leftrightarrow A = B$

I know that when two sets are equal, they they're the subsets of each other. What I don't understand is where the OP has brought this answer from.

Comment: Remember that two sets are equal if they have exactly the same elements.  If one of them, say $A$, has an element that $B$ doesn't, then what does that say about $A \cup B$ compared to $A \cap B$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by OP here? Are you attempting to reference another question on this site?

Comment: Do you have trouble understanding the argument for $A\subseteq B$ (and, with those two swapped, $B\subseteq A$)? Or do you have trouble understanding thy (1) and (2) imply that $A=B$?

Comment: The obvious part is $A,B \subset A \cup B$ and $A \cap B \subset A,B$.

Comment: But if $A \cup B = A \cap B$, then 1) becomes : $A \subset A \cap B \subset B$ and the subset relation is transitive. The same for 2).

Comment: The wording is uclear which clauses serve which functions.  "If, as, then" are not a dirty words.  I'd read these as 1) "As $A \subset A\cup B$ and $A\cup B = A\cap B$, and as $A\cap B \subset B$, we have $A \subset B$." And 2) "As $B \subset A\cup B$ and $A\cup B = A\cap B$, and as $A\cap B \subset a$, we have $B \subset A$."  Then your statement "I know that when two sets are equal, they they're the subsets of each other" really is the end of it all, right?

Comment: BTW way:  When you say OP that usually refers to ... you.  It's the phrase "where ... brought the answer from" that seems a little weird to me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522720/is-my-proof-for-a-cap-b-a-cap-c-longleftrightarrow-b-c-correct
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760342/prove-that-a-cup-b-a-cap-b-if-and-only-if-a-b
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783226/use-direct-proof-to-prove-if-a-cap-b-a-cap-c-and-a-cup-b-a-cup-c-t
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951669/let-a-b-and-c-be-sets-if-a-cup-b-a-cup-c-and-a-cap-b
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958465/verifying-my-proof-of-b-c
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042489/a-cap-b-a-cap-c-and-a-cup-b-a-cup-c-show-b-c

Answer (score 0):

Statement:

$A\cup B = A\cap B\rightarrow A=B$

Proof:

Assume $A\cup B = A\cap B$

This means $a\in A \lor a\in B \leftrightarrow a\in A\land a\in B$

Now  assume $a\in A$.
Thus $a\in A\lor a\in B$. As such $a\in A\land a\in B$. Therefore $a\in B$. As such$A\subseteq B$. (This line 1. of the quote).

And similar can be shown for $a\in B$ (line 2). Therefore $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the phrases are weird.  "then" doesn't really fit in the middle but if I edit them:

1) $A\subset A\cup B$, **(and  $A\cup B = A \cap B$)** $\require{cancel} \bcancel{\text{then}}$ **and** $A\cap B\subset B$, $\bcancel{\text{then}}$ **therefore** $A\subset B$.

2) $B\subset A\cup B$, **(and  $A\cup B = A \cap B$)** $ \bcancel{\text{then}}$ **and** $A\cap B\subset A$, $\bcancel{\text{then}}$ **therefore** $B\subset A$.

**(The results of)** 1) and 2) $\iff A=B$.

Does it become more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Contraposition:  If A is not B, A U B is a  proper superset of B is a proper superset of A intersection B. Thus   the union is not the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

B $\subseteq$ A $\cup$ B = A $\cap$ B $\subseteq$ A.
Likewise, A $\subseteq$ B.